# Automatic answer for file dialog in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to run Excel macro by using Python code. The problem is that at some point Excel macro ask for path to certain file by file dialog. Is it possible to respond to this file dialog automatically with Python script?

Comment: Not sure if that works, but look at win32com / pywin32  http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartClientCom.html

Comment: https://pbpython.com/windows-com.html